# Sufficient condition for a Hamilton cycle $C$ in a planar triangulation $G$ s.t. every triangle in $G$ has an edge in $C$

Tags: graph-theory, triangulations, hamiltonian-graphs, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a $k$-connected planar triangulation ($k\geq 4$) and let $C$ be a Hamilton cycle of $G$. Then:

1. Which conditions would be sufficient to assure that every triangle of $G$ has at least one edge belonging to the set of edges induced by $C$?
2. Or, does there exist at least one Hamilton cycle for every 4-connected planar triangulation or every 5-connected planar triangulation with property in (1)?

For example:
In picture below, not every triangle of $G$ has at least one edge belonging to the set of edges induced by the hamilton cycle $C_1$ (in red+blue)

[image: Picture 1]

However, in the next Figure, all triangles contains an edge belonging to the Hamilton cycle $C_2$ (in red):

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: By "a Hamiltonian cycle without such a property", do you mean the property in 1, and is that cycle contained in [p. 12 of the linked slides](https://nvcleemp.be/academic/docs/slides/graphdayULB13.pdf#page=12)? (Maybe that's not even a grammatically correct guess ….) If not, then which page is it? If so, then would you be willing to add, or would you mind my adding, an image of the relevant example, since slides on the web are not always long lived? \\ Also, please do not use $math\ mode$ for *emphasis*. I think there is no good way to do emphasis in the title.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/451678/revisions/3), thanks for your edit, I guess in response to my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1167794)! I think I was unclear, and I apologise: it is fine and appropriate to use math mode for math, like $C$ and $G$; it is just inappropriate to use it for text, like ‘$s.t.$’. Nonetheless, it is also fine and appropriate *not* to use math mode for math in the title, as long as it's consistent, so please feel free to leave it however you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gunnar Brinkmann informs me that [this paper](https://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/view/1733) constructs planar triangulations where every hamiltonian cycle misses all the edges of many triangles. Some of the examples are even 5-connected.

Comment: Thanks, strong result. Exactly what I needed to discard this hypothesis.

Comment: Hi, can the results of that paper be extended to more general class of planar graphs?  Say 4 regular?

Comment: @JoseAntonioMartinH  You should ask Gunnar. His email is easy to find.